# Using re.match() to find Substring

Tags: python, regex, string

How to search space separated string without using complex regular expression.
Here is My Code

```
import re
stringToQueryLevel1 = ['why this','why this code','why this code is complex']  
for i in range(stringToQueryLevel1.__len__()):
    if re.search('why this' , stringToQueryLevel1[i]) != None:
        rc = 0
    else:
        rc = 1

    print rc
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run, could you fix it and clarify your question. Also you aren't *meant* to be using the `__len__` method, it get's implicitly used by the `len()` function. The double underscores should have scared you away.

Comment: Also you don't need to write `range(stringToQueryLevel1.__len__()-1)` if you want to iterate over ALL elements of list (I think it's so), because `range()` will return `[0, ... len(stringToQueryLevel1) - 1]`

Comment: Also, in python you rarely iterate over integers to iterate over list. In this case you are better off iterating over actual list of data: `for row in stringToQueryLevel1:` and then `for item in row:` and so on...

Comment: My exact question is to search a space separated sub string  without using complex re.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple

```
stringToQueryLevel1 = ['why this', 'why this code', 'why this code is complex']
for item in stringToQueryLevel1:
    print ' ' in item
```

Comment: More readable version would be `print ' ' in item`

Comment: And it is also faster

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import re
stringToQueryLevel1 = ['why this','why this code','why this code is complex','TestTest'] 
for i in range(stringToQueryLevel1.__len__()): 
    if re.search('(\w+)\s(\w+)' , stringToQueryLevel1[i]) != None:
        print 'match found in %s'%(stringToQueryLevel1[i])
    else:
        print 'match not found in %s'%(stringToQueryLevel1[i])
```